# Is it possible to retrieve last N transactions or all transactions since a given timestamp?

Tags: transactions, javascript-sdk, stellar-sdk

The dapp I'm building can not rely on the paging mechanism described [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/examples.html), since after a short amount of time I will have a lot of transactions for a given account. Retrieving them all to only select a few more recent ones is very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/{ACCOUNT_ID}/transactions?order=desc&limit={N}
```

Where **ACCOUNT_ID** the account public key and **N** is the number of transactions you want to retrieve. Also note the order is descending (`&order=desc`)

See the [page reference](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/page.html).

Comment: Richard is right. If you need only the latest transactions, just use the "transactions for account" endpoint. You can retrieve up to 200 entries at a time (request with `limit` > 200 will return an error). To fetch more than 200 entries, you'll need to make a few subsequent requests using a `cursor` query parameter.

Comment: It works, I unintentionally ignored some parts of documentation, so for example in JS it would be:
server.transactions().forAccount(account).limit(200).order('desc').call().then( ... );

Comment: It's easily done...

Answer (score 0):

did you try using the .cursor(), something like:

server. transactions()
.forAccount(accountId)
.cursor(timestamp) ?